# How does 〜しなくても済んだだろう work?

Tags: grammar

> せめて親でも生きていてくれたら、**こんなに苦労しなくても済んだ**だろう
>
> I wouldn't have so many difficulties, if only my parents were still alive. *[Example sentence from Japanese Postpositions: Theory and Practice ISBN-13: 978-3895861116]*

As I understand it, the bolded part works like this:

- 苦労する: to be having trouble
- 苦労しない: to not be having trouble
- 苦労しなくて: connective form of the above
- 苦労しなくても: も added to emphasize `not having trouble`
- 済んだ: past form of 済む　added to mean "manage", "make do" (?)

With that in mind, to me the whole thing, 苦労しなくても済んだ, now means "managing/making do and **not** having trouble"? Considering the translation given by the book, how is it implied that the speaker **is** having difficulty?

Please note I do not actually understand how 済む is used here, grammar-wise. The above is just guesswork. I would appreciate some help on that as well.

The main question is, following the chain of logic above, possibly linked in me misunderstanding the use of も　and/or 済む:

Why is the negative form 苦労しない used here (but implying the speaker actually does 苦労) instead of the positive form?

Comment: これは楽しくない "This is really boring" _[Example sentence from a book]_. Shouldn't it be これは楽しい - this is really fun? Why is 楽しい negative? What is the grammar behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「せめて[親]{おや}でも[生]{い}きていてくれ**たら**、こんなに[苦労]{くろう}し**なくて**も[済]{す}んだだろう。」

First, this sentence is 100% natural, grammatical, etc.; It is perfect.  As a Japanese-speaker, I know that ***without*** even thinking. (考え**なくて**もわかる)　← Hint #1: "Without" ≒「なくて」

I am thinking to myself: 「もし、user9771さんも[日本語話者]{にほんごわしゃ}だっ**たら**、この[文]{ぶん}を[理解]{りかい}するのに**苦労しなくて済む**のに・・・」← Hint #2

> 「Verb phrase + なくて/ないで + (も) + [済]{す}む」
>
> = "can manage/survive/do/get through, etc. ***without*** (verb phrase)"

To express the "without" part, the verb phrase in Japanese ***MUST*** be in the negative form because you are essentially saying that you would make it if it were ***not*** for (something).

There is just no exception; The verb needs to be in the negative form.

> "What will happen if I use the ***affirmative*** form by mistake?" asks my imaginary Japanese-learner.

That will change the meaning of the sentence ***completely***!

Suppose you did not like eating raw fish but you were served sashimi as part of a course dinner.

You:「ボクのサシミ、[食]{た}べてくれない？そしたら、ボク**食べなくて**済むから。」

Guy:「[自分]{じぶん}で[食]{く}えよ。たった3-4[切]{き}れだろ？ささっと**食えば**済むんだから。」

You: "Could you eat my sashimi for me? So that I'll get through without eating it myself?  (And it'll save me from looking impolite)"

Guy: "Eat it yourself, man!  It's only a coupla tiny pieces, ain't it?  Just swallow it down quickly and dinner ***will be over***."

As you have seen above, I hope, if you used the affirmative verb form in front of 「済む」, the phrase would mean "(something) gets finished".  "To end completely" is one meaning of 「済む」.

> With that in mind, to me the whole thing, 苦労しなくても済んだ, now means "managing/making do and not having trouble"?

Exactly.

> Considering the translation given by the book, how is it implied that the speaker is having difficulty?

It is actually "stated clearly", and not "merely implied".  「こんなに～～ない」 means "not this much".  That would indicate there is an amount of (something) if not a whole lot, would it not?

> Why is the negative form 苦労しない used here (but implying the speaker actually does 苦労) instead of the positive form?

I hope I have already answered this, but you just have no choice but to use the negative verb form to express "to get by ***without*** ~~ing".  "Without" has a negative meaning, does it not?  It just is not a verb in English.

***In meaning***, would you not agree that "Without (verb)ing" = "With not (verb)ing" even though the latter may not be used in real life?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than emphasis, the も here gives to しなくても the meaning of without.

- *something* しなくて : Not doing *something*
- *something* しなくても : Without doing *something*

And the meaning of 済んだ is also more "(would) have ended up".

So the sentence is "it would probably (だろう) have ended up (済んだ) without such hardship (こんなに苦労しなくても)".